# Send bluetooth device name from service to activity

Tags: service, bluetooth

I created BlueService.java, from which I was able to get the Bluetooth name of the Bluetooth connected device. How can I pass the name to my MainActivity.

Comment: Try to implement android Broadcasts receivers, find there case for bluethoth
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: It works I used LocalBroadcastManager thanks.